# Toggle show only clicked one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I click on the details it `shows` all.
What I want is that he will only `toggle` the link detail that I click.

**[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/82mrnpp5/4/)**

**JS :**

```
$('.listt ul').hide();

$(document).on('click','.details a',function(){
    $('.listt ul').toggle();
});
```

Comment: see the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/82mrnpp5/1/

Comment: If i click on the second details it must only show of the second and not all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go up to the parent div width class `kop` using `.closest('.kop')` starting from the current clicked object `$(this)`, then target the next div with class `listt` using `.next('.listt')` :

```js
$('.listt').hide();

$(document).on('click','.details a',function(){
  $(this).closest('.kop').next('.listt').toggle();
})
```

```css
.kop
{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.kop div
{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="kop">
  <div class="name">John</div>
  <div class="details"><a href="#">(details)</a> </div>
</div>
<div class="listt">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="kop">
  <div class="name">John</div>
  <div class="details"><a href="#">(details)</a> </div>
</div>
<div class="listt">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: see the hiding part

Comment: Thnx Zakaria And for everyone who put their time into it i Thank u guys to

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.listt ul').hide();
$(document).on('click','.details a', function(){
 $('.listt ul').toggle();
});
```

```css
.kop {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.kop div{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kop">
  <div class="name">John</div>
  <div class="details"><a href="#">(details)</a> </div>
</div>


<div class="listt">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="kop">
  <div class="name">John</div>
  <div class="details"><a href="#">(details)</a> </div>
</div>

<div class="listt">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```